# Speed of light at low temperatures

Tags: visible-light, temperature, speed-of-light, refraction

From my understanding the temperature in a black hole nears absolute zero. Also some experiments have shown that light can be slowed. 1) is this true?

Matter cannot reach the speed of light, yet light speed can be reduced in the correct medium. If you can reduce light speed to a velocity that matter can travel. Then can’t you argue that something can travel at the speed of light?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can exceed the special speed $c$, which is the speed of light *in vacuum*. In other materials light goes slower, and particles can in fact go faster than light does *in that material*, but not faster than light goes in a vacuum. Particles traveling faster than light in a material have been observed because they emit [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation). But again, while they are going "faster than light" in a particular medium, they are still moving slower than $c$.

Temperature only affects the speed of light in a material, not the speed of light in vacuum. The gravity of a black hole is such that escape velocity from its event horizon is larger than $c$, so nothing can escape it.

Note that light doesn't intrinsically have some special property that prevents things from going faster than it. It just happens that because the photons that make up light are massless, they can and do travel as fast as anything possibly can in a vacuum. We could equally well call $c$ "the speed of gravity" (it is!) or "the maximum speed of information transfer".

Comment: I recently read a comment on here stating that light doesn't travel actually travel slower in a material but takes a longer path through that material which makes it appear to. But I can't confirm or explain either way.